# Keep main thread wait until RxJava Observable complete

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to hold my main thread until RxJava 2 Observable complete. My coding is as here. The case is when I request the method contains below code, method was just executing without waiting for observable

```
 Observable
                        .fromArray(observableList)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Observable<List<String>>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(List<Observable<List<String>>> list) throws Exception {

                            for (Observable<List<String>> observable : list) {
                                System.out.println("Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                                observable.subscribe(new Consumer<List<String>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(List<String> t) throws Exception {

                                        Gson jsonBuilder = new Gson();

                                        Object obj = new Object();

                                        JsonElement element = jsonBuilder.toJsonTree(obj);

                                        element.getAsJsonObject().addProperty(t.get(0), t.get(1));

                                        Gson g = new Gson();
                                        Object out = g.fromJson(t.get(1), Object.class);

                                        microResponses.put(t.get(0), out);
                                    }
                                });

                            }

                        }


         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need multi-level subscribe, and you shouldn't need to nest your Observables:

```
Oservable
.fromArray(observableList)
.flatMapIterale(i -> i)
.flatMap(i -> i)
.doOnNext(t -> {
   Gson jsonBuilder = new Gson();
   Object obj = new Object();
   JsonElement element = jsonBuilder.toJsonTree(obj);
   element.getAsJsonObject().addProperty(t.get(0), t.get(1));
   Gson g = new Gson();
   Object out = g.fromJson(t.get(1), Object.class);
   microResponses.put(t.get(0), out);
})
// .subscribe(...) or .doOnComplete(...).subscribe();
;
```

However, your code as written has several issues:

- the first four lines are a no-op, as you're not using the JsonElement.
- Why not use `new JsonObject()` directly?
- the `Object out = g.fromJson(t.get(1), Object.class);` will not produce anything besides an empty JsonObjecy, as an `Object` does not have any properties.
- Why are you using List, and not something that makes actual sense, like a `Map.Entry<String,Object>`, or even an `Pair<String, Object>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use any one below:-
1. Remove subscribeOn
2. Use Thread.sleep for time large enough for your task to complete
3. Google toBlocking usage in rxjava